# Select from three tables in Laravel WITHOUT specifying ON

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have this query which when I run it in phpmyadmin it's returning what I want

```
SELECT c.category_id, c.category_name, sc.sub_cat_id, sc.sub_cat_name, dsc.dual_sub_cat_id, dsc.dual_sub_cat_name
FROM category c
JOIN sub_category AS sc
JOIN dual_sub_category AS dsc
```

I want to write it in Laravel query now and I've tried this

```
$cat_display = DB::table('category')
    ->join ('sub_category')
    ->join ('dual_sub_category')
    ->get();
```

The error is

> ErrorException: Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::join()

As I understand the error it is said I need to add also `ON` clause on both joins but I don't want to because I don't have by what to match them.

I just want to query and display this fields from this 3 tables. Is it possible without `ON` and `WHERE` clauses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via a Laravel Relation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

First, create a `Category` model.

Then after define two relation inside `Category` model like below.

```
class Category extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'category';

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function subCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class, 'category_id', 'category_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function dualSubCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DualSubCategory::class, 'category_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Note: `SubCategory` and `DualSubCategory` are models.

In Controller your function use this below code.

```
$cat_display = Category::with(['subCategory','dualSubCategory'])->get()
```

Let me know if you face here any issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've got this error: `production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Exception\PlainDisplayer::display() must be an instance of Exception, instance of ParseError given`

Comment: But as I said I don't have anything that connects the tables. Like this I should have in `subCategory` and `dualSubCategory` columns `category_id`

Comment: Can you share your table structure for this three table ?

Comment: each table has id column and name column, like: `category_id | category_name`, `sub_category_id | sub_category_name` and `dual_sub_category_id | dual_sub_category_name`

Comment: You have any relation between category and sub category  or  dual sub category ?

Comment: No. That's why I want query without **ON** and **WHERE** clauses. I just want to get them

Comment: If you want this data in single query then must need to add category_id into sub category and dual category table.  Or if you don't want to add category_id then you can do this way with three different query.

Comment: $category = DB::table('category')->get();   $sub_category = DB::table('sub_category')->get();, $dualSubCategory = DB::table('user_roles')->get('dual_sub_category');

Comment: It's not an option. This will require a lot of re-writes. Should be in one query

Comment: Then you must need to add category_id into sub category and dual sub catgory table.

Comment: But there is no point in the application to save `category_id` in `dual_sub_category`. I agree for `sub_category` but no point on `dual_sub_category`

Comment: What is ideal data in dual_sub_category ?

Comment: Sorry for a late answer. This is the data in `dual_sub_category`: `ID`, `Name`, `Sub_cat_id`

Comment: Remove this code from Category Model. And add into Sub Category Model.

Comment: public function dualSubCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DualSubCategory::class, 'Sub_cat_id', 'Sub_cat_id');
    }

Comment: $cat_display = Category::with(['subCategory','subCategory.dualSubCategory'])->get()

Answer (score 2):

you can do this like so

```
$cat_display = DB::table('category as c')
    ->join ('sub_category as sc', 'category.id', '=', 'category.id')
    ->join ('dual_sub_category as dsc', 'category.id', '=', 'category.id')
    ->select('c.category_id', 'c.category_name', 'sc.sub_cat_id', 'sc.sub_cat_name', 'dsc.dual_sub_cat_id', 'dsc.dual_sub_cat_name')
    ->get();
```

By giving the join condition something that will always evaluate to true, it acts similarly to having no condition at all :)

This does assume though that your category table has a column named id. If this is not the case, then choose any column from the table to evaluate to itself.

EDIT

Ok, so the code above should give you the same output using Laravel's query builder from your pure SQL statements. I think before you were not getting the all data you wanted was due to not selecting the columns. Again I tried this using 3 tables on my own system and was getting the same result from the mysql terminal as Laravel :) Let me know if everything was OK.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I display now names and ID's from each table? Because when I foreach them now I get only first row from each table only

Comment: @Rohit I doubt that @Bryan meant this. Since I said that tables aren't connected it's mean that I don't have `category_id` column in each table.

Comment: Hi there, yes VLS sorry I did not mean to edit the answer. The answer I gave should have given the same result as your pure mySQL statement. I tried on some tables of mine that have a similar structure. I will edit my answer back and add a fix that should stop the duplicate rows showing

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. Let me know how the new code works and if you have any troubles :)

Comment: Hm.. strange but they're still doublet when I try to display category name like `@foreach($cat_display as $cats) <p>{{ $cats->category_name }}</p>@endforeach`